# How to fasten learning without changing learning rate in linear regression

Tags: machine-learning

Whenever I made a linear regression model, it just diverged, all the time. I really couldn't find any solutions for that. But when I changed the learning rate to 0.0000252, it worked! But another problem is that it learns so slowly so that I have to wait for the model to learn for more than 10 minutes.

How can I fasten learning without changing the learning rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question is: why use SGD (which i assume here). There are more specialized learning-procedures for Linear-regression, which partially do not need that kind of hyperparameter-tuning. Maybe you are in a very large-scale setting then where SGD is a valid approach.

Assuming SGD-based learning is the way to go:

- You should use some kind of learning-schedule

  - Add at least a learning-rate decay, which reduces the learning-rate for example after each epoch by a factor of something like 0.9 (yes, one more hyperparameter)
  - Try to use some kind of momentum, e.g. Nesterov-momentum which was developed for convex-optimization (your case is convex) and holds strong guarantees

    - This kind of momentum is even popular in the non-convex setting
    - Most DeepLearning libs should provide this out-of-the-box
- You can try adaptive learning-rate based algorithms like:

  - Adam, AdaDelta, AdaGrad, ...
  - These try to remove the burden from selecting those LR-hyperparameters while still trying to convergence as quickly as possible

    - Of course they are heuristics (strictly spoken), but they seem to work well for most people (although an optimized SGD is most of the time the best)
    - Most DeepLearning libs should provide this out-of-the-box
- Use specialized software for linear-models like [liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) or others

And one more thing, because i''m surprised that it's that easy to observe divergence on this simple problem: **normalize your input!**